# A jquery means to the end of changing every(as in each and all) href value to a corresponding array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

my question is while vague, specific. I would like to know the simplest means of changing each and every (10+) anchor tags href value to a corresponding array item. the page in question being constructed from the bottom up meaning that each new post is above the last new post, so I have an array of links starting with the link that corresponds to the bottom most and thereby first placed and last in order post.  so far (in theory) I think  that a variable that returns each array value a reverse traversal of that array that is used in a function that selects and traverses each anchor tag would be the solution.

```
var standard_anchor = new Array(); 
standard_anchor[0] = "http://whatever.com/";
standard_anchor[1] = "http://www.egs.edu/faculty/jean-baudrillard/articles/simulacra-and-simulations-viii-the-implosion-of-meaning-in-the-media/";

var standard = $(function(){
    //should return reversed iterated standard anchor array
            });


////

$('a [href]').each(function(){return (standard)});
```

that's as much as I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919), it's a live collection so you only need one reference, it will update as the DOM is updated.

You can iterate over it backwards using a while loop:

```
var links = document.links;
var i = links.length;
while (i--) {
  // do stuff with links[i]
}
```